# "... can already been seen ..." grammatically correct?

Tags: passive-voice

In a recent issue of Bloomberg Businessweek, there is a sentence "The shift can already been seen." Is this grammatically correct? Or does it omit something, or actually a typo (can -> have)? I searched the web and found numerous similar uses (https://www.google.com/search?client=firefox-b-1-d&q=%22can+already+been+seen%22), but I do not quite understand how to grammatically justify such use.

Comment: My guess: an error introduced by an incomplete edit.  Should be either  "can already be seen" or "has already been seen".  I suspect an edit would changing one of these to the other, but done incompletely.  *Can* should be followed by an infinitive, such as *be*, while *has* may be followed by a past participle, such as *been*

Comment: When 'already' gets into 'can be seen', it sounds self-contradicting.

Comment: Gotta be a typo in Bloomberg: "Demand for used cars ... rising ... over the next five years. The shift can already **been seen**. Doesn't make it standard English.